# Put labels inside stacked bar and customize legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I have to create a horizontal stacked bar. But I need to put the percentage inside the bar, and the customized legend beside the figure.

This is my code in latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar stacked,
        bar width = 25pt,
        xmin = -1, 
        xmax = 101,
        symbolic y coords={C, C++, Java, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby},
        x tick label style={font=\small},
        xticklabels = {,,},
        ]
    \addplot+[xbar, blue!50!green, thick, fill=white] plot coordinates
        {(91,C) (87,C++) (72,Java) (91,JavaScript) (93,PHP) (91,Python) (87,Ruby)};
    \addplot+[xbar, red, thick, fill=white] plot coordinates
        {(9,C) (13,C++) (28,Java) (9,JavaScript) (7,PHP) (9,Python) (13,Ruby)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code only shows the stacked bar without the labels inside the bar and I need to add the legend beside the graph.
This is the graph I would like to see:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had a crack at it and worked out a way. I used nodes near coords for the percentages within the bars. Furthermore, I used `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry` for the legend beside the chart. Also I changed `compat=` to `1.9`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar stacked,
        bar width = 25pt,
        xmin = -1, 
        xmax = 101,
        symbolic y coords={C, C++, Java, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby},
        x tick label style={font=\small},
        xticklabels = {,,},
        legend style={at={(1.05,0.6)},anchor=north west, draw=none},         
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
        point meta = explicit symbolic     
        ]
    \addlegendimage{empty legend},    
    \addplot+[xbar, blue!50!green, thick, fill=white] plot coordinates
        {(91,C)[91]
        (87,C++)[87] 
        (72,Java)[72] 
        (91,JavaScript)[91] 
        (93,PHP)[93] 
        (91,Python)[91] 
        (87,Ruby)[87]};
    \addplot+[xbar, red, thick, fill=white] plot coordinates
        {(9,C)[9]
        (13,C++)[13]
        (28,Java)[28] 
        (9,JavaScript)[9] 
        (7,PHP)[7] 
        (9,Python)[9] 
        (13,Ruby)[13]};

    \addlegendentry{\hspace{-.6cm}\textbf\small{Type}},
    \addlegendentry{Seed},
    \addlegendentry{No seed},
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
I am pretty new to this, so my coding can come across a bit mundane. I hope this helps. All the best!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: It might be good if you could add an image of the result, so everyone can see it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and editing. I am learning a lot here.